# how to use the spring.redis.host defined value inside the spring boot service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I had defined spring redis host and spring redis port in application.properties . How to use it inside the service classes?

Answer (score 0):

Read it using `@ConfigurationProperties(value = "spring.redis.port")` where spring.redis.port is the hierarchy of the property and might differ in your code.

Comment: @Component
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "spring.redis.host")
public class JedisClientPool implements JedisClient {

 @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
 private String redisHost;

 @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
 private int redisPort;
hello mam,is it the right way or else any alternative is required?